# Why does using static resources break the designer in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a resource dictionary in a class library that has a bunch of SolidColorBrush's and Control style's. It works in the designer when i make sure that all the controls whose style i am setting are using DynamicResource's but if i switch it to use a StaticResource either the designer breaks or my application fails to run... or both.

*This works*

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Style="{DynamicResource DriveImageStyle}"/>
```

*This breaks*

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Style="{StaticResource DriveImageStyle}"/>
```

giving me errors such as:

> XamlParseException: Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.
>
> Cannot find resource named 'DriveImageStyle'

When using resources in the resource dictionaries themselves (setting the background colour of a style)

*This works*

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundColour}" />
```

*This breaks*

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColour}" />
```

and gives me errors in the designer such as:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: '{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a
>   valid value for property 'Background'.

Can anyone give me a reason as to why it acts in this way?

*Additional information*

In my View's I reference the dictionary like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles;component/Resources.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

And I merge them in my class library like so:

```
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Colours.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Buttons.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Comment: For the first part, I believe it is because it is in a class library, not in just in your project, so it has to dynamically locate it. I tried it with a resource dictionary inside a project and both static and dynamic worked just fine. For the second part, if static resource have to be defined prior to using them so that may be the issue

Comment: How are you referencing it in your mergeddictionaries from your resource dictionary? Show us your pack URI.

Comment: @ChrisW. I have updated my question with the info you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I had time to go test but I want to say this is how I did it last time I was using directly from a usercontrol. However I'd generally advise against it and just slap it over in the app.xaml of the proj or someplace more centralized unless that one view is genuinely the only one need it. Either way give this a shot instead, they can be finnicky about details.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles;component/Resources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```